# Another route to get actual REG_DWORD decimal number from registry in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, registry, getvalue, dword

I have been using GetValue with GetValueKind and have just come across an issue when Reading DWORD that is larger than the signed 32-bit integer. I am able to Write to to the registry without restriction, getting to the max of 4294967295 (ffffffff in hex).

If there was a way to do this with int64 then I wouldnt be restricted..

I could make this work if I could read the hexadecimal value, which i could just convert to decimal via int64, though again, I dont know how i would read the hex value from the registry..

Is there another route I should take to allow me to Read the correct value when it exceeds the signed 32-bit integer value of 2,147,483,647?

thanks

Comment: Does it not just wrap around to Integer.MinValue ? i.e. you write -1 and end up with 0xffffffff or, you write -2,147,483,648 and end up with 0x80000000

Comment: How about you start by showing us the actual code you're using now? ALWAYS provide the relevant code.

Comment: @CaiusJard I see the results and how youre right about that, but not sure how that i could use that information

Comment: What I'm saying is that a signed integer and an unsigned integer are the same thing; if you set your value to 0xfffffffe in regedit then it will say it's 4294967294, and if you read it in .net it will say it's -2, because unsigned 4294967295 = -2 signed. None of it needs to go through int64, you just need to understand that e.g. -1, 4294967295 and 0xffffffff are all the same thing. If you use .net to write -3, your regedit will show 4294967293 or 0xfffffffd. int goes from 0 to 2,147,483,647 (0x7fffff) then if you add 1 to it it becomes -2,147,483,648 (as an int) or 2,147,483,648 as a uint

Comment: @CaiusJard I appreciate your input, quite helpful in regards to understanding the units.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Dim PATH as string = "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Test"
Dim NAME as string = "TestName"
Dim ft As String = "DOES_NOT_EXIST"
Dim gv As Object = Registry.GetValue(PATH, NAME, ft)
Dim gb As Byte() = BitConverter.GetBytes(CInt(gv))
Dim j As UInt32 = BitConverter.ToUInt32(gb, 0)
Textbox1.text = j
```

Answer (score 0):

DWORD is a 32-bit unsigned integer - not a signed integer, so use `UInt32` instead.

According to [2.2.9 DWORD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-dtyp/262627d8-3418-4627-9218-4ffe110850b2)

> A DWORD is a 32-bit unsigned integer (range: 0 through 4294967295
> decimal). Because a DWORD is unsigned, its first bit (Most Significant
> Bit (MSB)) is not reserved for signing.

[Data Type Summary (Visual Basic)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/data-types/)

[image]
[image]

**Resources**:

- [Windows Data Types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog/windows-data-types)

Comment: Thanks for your response, though I was getting at the fact that the function GetValue, uses signed integers. I am unable to get the value to Unsigned with my current code. Textbox1.text = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(PATH, False).GetValue(NAME)

Comment: @user9938 your DataType Summary is right, but it's misleading. It would perhaps be more helpful to say "int goes from 0 to 2,147,483,647 then -2,147,483,648 to -1"; go into project properties advanced compile and turn off overflow checks and set an int to int.MaxValue. Then add 1 to it; it's now int.MinValue

Comment: @CaiusJard awesome thanks for your input dude. I did manage to figure it out by getting the bytes first, then converting it from there. I posted what worked for me above